# summation of user input in a loop

Tags: c++

I made a little store system and i put a code for each product(like barcode) and user will enter these codes, and I want to make a system that gives this code and input the price, and do this few times, but I don't know how to summation these price that known by user barcode input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input_code, count, i; //the list of product are here
    float price;
    cout << "\t  -code-  -product-  -price-  \n";
    cout << "\t  101     wather   0.99$   \n";
    cout << "\t  102     milk    1.5$    \n";

    cout << "how many product do you want?";
    cin >> count; //the number of user product

    do {
        cin >> input_code; //input code of user
        switch (input_code) {
        case 101:
            price = 0.99;
            break;
        case 102:
            price = 1.5;
            break;
        }
        sum = price; // sum of all price that user put them code
        i++;
    } while (i < count);
    cout << sum << "$";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare `sum`? Depending on how it's declared and initialized, you may just be able to change `sum = price;` to `sum += price`.

Comment: Maybe just ```sum += price```?

Comment: initialize `i` variable to `0` and same for `sum` and change `sum = price` to `sum += price`

Comment: Was `=` instead of `+=` intentional?  Or is this just a facepalm typo situation?

Comment: yes guys thanks it is    sum += price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you want to sum all the items a simple solution would be to declare sum = 0 at the start, and later on when you add an item make it sum = sum + price.

Comment: thanks guys , problem was sum=price that it should change to   sum+=price

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you should fist declare sum as a double and assign it to 0 and then use `sum += price`.

Adittionally, you should also consider replace the `do while` loop with a `for` loop for readability, checking if the `std::cin` input is a valid number replacing `using namespace std;` with `using std::cout` and `using std::cin` and rename `count` to something else to avoid errors with the names as `std` already contains a function template called `count`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int input_code, number, i;  //the list of product are here
    float sum = 0;
    cout << "\t  -code-  -product-  -price-  \n" ;
    cout << "\t  101     wather   0.99$   \n" ;
    cout << "\t  102     milk    1.5$    \n" ;
    cout << "How many products do you want? " ;
    cin >> number; //the number of user product
    while(cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "That's not a valid value!\n";
        cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
        cin.clear();
        cin >> number;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter code: ";
        cin >> input_code;  //input code of user
        while(cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "That's not a valid value!\n";
            cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
            cin.clear();
            cin >> input_code;
        }
        switch (input_code)
        {
        case 101 :
            sum += 0.99;
            break ;
        case 102:
            sum += 1.5;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong Code! \n";
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
     cout << sum << "$";
     return 0;
}
```